# Why doesnt my accessory attach to the player in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

The custom Accessory does not attach to the player and spawns away from him

Here is my script

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local human = player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local asset = game.ReplicatedStorage.UnionAccessory:Clone()
human:AddAccessory(asset)
```

I was expecting that the player would just have Accessory equiped and would walk with it, but that didnt happen

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to add an attachment for the accessory. Without attachment it will just fall off.